# Taking a screenshot in Android app using Java without using Window/Decor view from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, screenshot

I'm currently working on an Android app and I'm facing an issue with taking screenshots programmatically. I want to capture a screenshot of the current activity's view without including the **Window/Decor** view. I have tried the traditional approach of using `getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()`

I did some research on this topic and didn't find it useful. Then I had an idea what about using this approach instead

I want to hit the default/traditional screenshot from the Android app code. e.g. **Shutter bar screenshot, three-finger screenshot or using power and volume buttons.**

Comment: "I want to hit the default/tradition screenshot from android app code. e.g. Shutter bar screenshot, three finger screenshot or using power and volume button" -- that "captures the whole screen, including the status and navigation bars", which is what you say that you do not want.